# Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I am facing this error when i attach specific datasource with dropdownlist. with all other tables/datasources its working fine.
I am not doing any changes in dropdownlist using javascript/jquery (as its working fine with all other datasource except current)

error:

> ```
> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is
> ```
>
> enabled using  in configuration
>   or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in  a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid  and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to 
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

my function to get values from xml files:

```
public List<ProductReviewmaster> ConvertRssXDocToReviews(XDocument xdoc)
{
    List<ProductReviewmaster> nl = new List<ProductReviewmaster>();

    if (xdoc != null)
    {
        var res = from rs in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                  select new ProductReviewmaster()
                  {
                      Title = rs.Element("title").Value,
                      ShortHeadLine = rs.Element("shortheadline").Value,
                      Link = rs.Element("link").Value,
                      Reviewid = rs.Element("guid").Value ,
                      //Pubdate = Convert.ToDateTime( rs.Element("pubdate").Value),
                      Image = rs.Element("storyimage").Value,
                      Dateline = rs.Element("dateline").Value,
                      Excerpt = rs.Element("excerpt").Value,
                      Tags = rs.Element("tags").Value,
                      ProductId = rs.Attribute("productid").Value.ToInt64()
                  };
        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            nl.Add(item);

        }
    }
    return nl;


}
```

This is how i am binding it with my dropdownlist:

```
   ddlReview.DataSource =  prmf.GetReviewByCategoryKey(categoryid);
                ddlReview.DataValueField = "Reviewid";
                ddlReview.DataTextField = "Title";
                ddlReview.DataBind();
                ddlReview.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---"));
```

When i bind same dropdownlist with any other datasource (non-xml) its working fine .. but when i am doing it with this datasource its throwing that above error.

My xml is like:

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>

        </title>
    <link>

        </link>
    <language>en</language>
    <lastBuildDate>
            August  3, 2011  3:57 PM
        </lastBuildDate>
    <image>
      <url></url>
      <link>
            </link>
    </image>
    <items>
      <item productid="">
        <title><![CDATA[This is new test review]]></title>
        <shortheadline><![CDATA[]]></shortheadline>
        <link>

                    </link>
        <permaLink>
          <web>

                        </web>
        </permaLink>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">
                        29527
                    </guid>
        <pubDate>
                        August  2, 2011  1:56 PM
                    </pubDate>
        <MobileText></MobileText>
        <storyimage><![CDATA[ges/apple-appstore.jpg]]></storyimage>
        <categories><![CDATA[mobile]]></categories>
        <dateline><![CDATA[]]></dateline>
        <excerpt><![CDATA[isational structure for its operations in India and South Asia with effetransformational business...]]></excerpt>
        <tags><![CDATA[mobile, phone]]></tags>
        <contenttype><![CDATA[Review]]></contenttype>
      </item>
    </items>
    <description></description>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

its successfully retriving data and showing on dropdownlist but when i select any item from it (selected index changed) then it shows this message...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issue...
while using LINQ, i just used Trim() and its done... :)

```
var res = from rs in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                          select new ProductReviewmaster()
                          {
                              Title = rs.Element("title").Value.Trim(),
                              ShortHeadLine = rs.Element("shortheadline").Value.Trim(),
                              Link = rs.Element("link").Value.Trim(),
                              Reviewid = rs.Element("guid").Value.Trim() ,
                              //Pubdate = Convert.ToDateTime( rs.Element("pubdate").Value),
                              Image = rs.Element("storyimage").Value.Trim(),
                              Dateline = rs.Element("dateline").Value.Trim(),
                              Excerpt = rs.Element("excerpt").Value.Trim(),
                              Tags = rs.Element("tags").Value.Trim(),
                              ProductId = rs.Attribute("productid").Value.ToInt64()
                          };
```

so my final conclusion is there must me problem of blank space with value...

Answer (score 1):

That error usually crops up when your input elements, including drop downlists, contains either of these characters '<' or '>'.

Have you tried encoding those values if they exist?